# SOLR Field not reflected in schema browser

Tags: solr

I created a solr core using bin/solr -c core1 and then copied the schema.xml file from basic config set to core1/conf folder and added a  field

`<field name="title" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`.

But this field is not reflected in schema browser.
What configurations should I make to get the new fields reflected in schema browser in solr admin ui?

I am using solr 5.3.1

Comment: In admin panel can you able to see newly ceated core i.e. core1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default when you create a solr core it will use managed schema. You will see the following configuration in solrconfig.xml after core is created.

```
 <schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
    <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
    <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
  </schemaFactory>
```

Above this configuration you will find the comments on how use managed-schema. Comment this out and uncomment the following to use schema.xml

```
<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I can see some changes in the startup screen now, although startup fails with following error: `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: fieldType 'booleans' not found in the schema`

Comment: booleans field type may not be defined in your schema.xml

Comment: +1. I spent 4 hours trying to figure this out. Thought I must be making some mistake in configuring fields. Coming from 3.x this wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reload the core: go to http://yourhost:8983/solr/#/~cores/core1 and press "Reload" button.